# Encoding issue with French language characters when creating RTF document using .NET/C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, rtf

The app is developed in .NET and reads an RTF document template that contains placeholders that require replacing with text currently stored in a SQL Server database. The app then saves the RTF doc with the substituted text. However, French characters read from the database, such as é are being displayed as Ã© in the RTF document.

The process is:

1. read the RTF doc
2. replace the placeholders with data from SQL Server db
3. save to new RTF doc

The key bits of the code I think are...

**Read from RTF doc:**

```
StringBuilder buffer;
using (StreamReader input = new StreamReader(pathToTemplate))
{
    buffer = new StringBuilder(input.ReadToEnd());
}
```

**Replace placeholder text with text from database:**

```
buffer.Replace("$$placeholder$$", strFrenchCharsFromDb);
```

**Save the edits as a new RTF doc:**

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer.ToString());

File.WriteAllBytes(pathToNewRtfDoc, fileBytes);
```

When I debug `buffer` during "Save" the é character is present.
When I open the RTF after `File.WriteAllBytes` it contains Ã© instead.

I have tried specifying the encoding when creating the StreamReader but it was the same result.
i.e. `using (StreamReader input = new StreamReader(pathToTemplate, Encoding.UTF8))`

Comment: The default font in your RTF viewer may be set to wrong font.  Code may be working properly.

Comment: @mikepoole72: You should set the required font. It can be defined for the entire document or, if your document uses different fonts, only for the parts of document to which the replacing (_placeholder_) is applied.  Note that the non-ASCII characters must be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following method on the `strFrenchCharsFromDb` string before caling the `Replace()`:

```cs
buffer.Replace("$$placeholder$$", ConvertNonAsciiToEscaped(strFrenchCharsFromDb));
```

The `ConvertNonAsciiToEscaped()` method implementation:

```cs
/// <param name="rtf">An RTF string that can contain non-ASCII characters and should be converted to correct format before loading to the RichTextBox control.</param>
/// <returns>The source RTF string with converted non ASCII to escaped characters.</returns>

public string ConvertNonAsciiToEscaped(string rtf)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in rtf)
    {
        if (c <= 0x7f)
            sb.Append(c);
        else
            sb.Append("\\u" + Convert.ToUInt32(c) + "?");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Western European (ISO)" encoding method:  `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`